# Webapi 2 ApplicationContext missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having difficulty finding the 'ApplicationContext' in a WebApi 2 default project. In an MVC5 app there is a class in Models called ApplicationContext that uses the ConnectionString defined in web.config:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Its easy to add DbSets and have a all data in one context in an MVC5 web page project, however I cant find this class in a webapi 2 project.

There has to be a class that extends DbContext or IdentityDbContext somewhere in the WebApi project that also uses the connection string but I've searched through the whole project and can't find it. Is it possible to have an applicationwide DbContext in an webapi 2 project that has all the account data (usernames, pw hashes, roles, externallogins, etc) and all other data defined by me (DbSets)?

There appears to be a UserManager class in the ApiController but I see no way how to add my own custom data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ApplicationDbContext** class isn't part of the framework, so you have to add it yourself. If it is not included in the templates you can easily add it  yourself like you have done in your code snippet. In your case you would create a context derived from **IdentityDbContext**, which in turn derives from **DbContext**. In this context you can add your custom **DbSet's**. If you have trouble to create this context copy it from your existing MVC5 project (which I guess you have already in place) to your Web API project.

If there are any errors, make sure that you'll have the appropriate NuGet references in your project, especially to the Entity Framework implementation of ASP.NET Identity.

Comment: But how is it possible to set [Required] and [StringLength] attributes for IdentityUser for example? I tried to add a DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users to the newly created ApplicationContext and use EntityTypeConfigurations to configure the Required and Stringlength attribute but I got this error: 
Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'Users' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'Applicationuser' (extends IdentityUser). So right now I'm left with a database where nulls are allowed and there is no restriction on username lengths (other than the bindingmodel).

Comment: You don't have to add a *DbSet* for your *IdentityUser* implementation. That's the reason why you get this error message. The *null* values are definitely a problem, but you mentioned already a good workaround: Set the attributes on your view/binding models. If you do it correctly users of the API can't insert a user name with a lenght f.e. of thirty characters.